# Change Application language configuration based on user selection

Tags: xamarin, localization, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make my Xamarin Forms application support multiple language like English and Arabic which is based on user selection not based on phone language.
The following code shows how I change my language to Arabic or English.

The following code is a part of the TranslateExtension from the [Xamarin Forms Samples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization/PagesXaml/TranslateExtension.cs):

```
public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (Text == null)
        return "";
    ResourceManager resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId, typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

    var translation = resmgr.GetString(Text, ci);
    if (translation == null)
    {
#if DEBUG
        throw new ArgumentException(
        String.Format("Key '{0}' was not found in resources '{1}' for culture '{2}'.", Text, ResourceId, ci.Name),"Text");
#else
        translation = Text; // HACK: returns the key, which GETS DISPLAYED TO THE USER
#endif
    }
    return translation;
}
```

Can anyone help me and tell me how to make this work based on user selection not based on device language. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the code you pasted came from [this example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization/PagesXaml/TranslateExtension.cs). Based on that example, you can see there is a variable `ci` which contains the CultureInfo on which the extension works.

So the solution to your problem is setting that `ci` variable correctly. If the user selects a locale, you probably save that somewhere. In the TranslateExtension constructor, you can then retrieve that locale from where you saved it.

Something like:

```cs
public TranslateExtension() {
    var userlocaleSvc = DependencyService.Get<IUserLocale>();
    if (userlocaleSvc.CustomCultureInfoSet()) // this method is made up
    {
        ci = userlocaleSvc.GetCultureInfo(); // this method is made up
    } else {
        ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo(); // fallback
    }
}
```

You can also set the CultureInfo on the Resource, so resources that don't use the TranslateExtension also get translated properly (AppResources is the name you give your resource file, you can use any name you want):

```cs
AppResources.Culture = new CultureInfo ("<shortcode of selected locale>");
```

Refer to the [Xamarin documentation on localization here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/)